# I am trying to arrange my html/css/jquery so I can toggle the visibility of a div by double clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to arrange my html/css/jquery so I can toggle the visibility of a
div by double clicking on it. I can make it hidden by a double click **but when I
double click again it does not reappear.** When I check to see all of the div outlines,
the outline of this div is no longer there. I use a web developer plugin to check.
I am using the following codes to try to accomplish this:

My **css classes** are..

```
  .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
    .unhidden { visibility: visible; }
```

the **html** is...

```
<div id="ConstructionDiv" ondblclick="unhide('ConstructionDiv')" class="unhidden">
                    <!.. the div is unhidden at page load. When I look at generated
                    source code after the double click the class is "hidden" 
                     -->
            </div>
```

**my javascript** is...

```
function unhide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) {
 item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
 }
 }
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying? There must be something that works. 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think you can click on invisible elements, try setting opacity to 0 instead

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and invisible elements cannot receive click events.

As Andy said, Opacity 0 can receive click events just fine, and the contents are still invisible.

Comment: Hello, I succeeded  with this html
 <div  ondblclick="unhide('ConstructionDiv')"  id="ConstructionDiv" style="opacity:0"  >
...
</div>

and with this javascript.
function unhide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) {
 item.style.opacity=(item.style.opacity==0)?1:0;
 }
 }

Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css rules:

```
    .hidden {
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=1);
        -moz-opacity:.1;
        -khtml-opacity: .1;
        opacity: .1;
    }

.unhidden {
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        -moz-opacity:1;
        -khtml-opacity: 1;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You can also wrap the element in some other element like div and then use the click of that div to show or hide the inner content.

Comment: This doesn't work either. You can't interact with an element with an opacity of 0 either.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have two divs, both placed absolutely, but one possibly much larger than the other.  clicking one changes the visibility of both of them.